# MVC delete image with Ajax and remove image on success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I can delete an image and information in the database using ajax but have a bit of code to remove the image from the page when it's successfully been deleted from the database.

The issue is it isn't removing the image from the page after deletion. I placed my code to remove the image from the page outside of my ajax request and it worked fine but won't work when in the success section of the ajax request.

Any ideas?

It is this line that won't work `$(this).closest('.property-image').remove();`

```
$(".delete-image").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

            var id = $(this).data('id');

            console.log("clicked:" + id);

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("DeletePropertyImage")',
                data: JSON.stringify({ Id: id }),
                dataType: 'HTML',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: true,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(this).closest('.property-image').remove();
                    console.log("deleted:" + id)
                },
                error: function (__x, __h, __m) {
                    console.log('ajax returned error', __m, __x, __h);
                }

            });
    });
```

Comment: Can you add some sample HTML?  Hard to tell without that.

Comment: The `this` is no longer the same `this` you think it is. You'll need to save it outside of the callback function `var _this = this` then use `_this`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/2030565

Comment: Looks like you have the id already, can't you just do a $('#'+ id).remove()?